# How to Get Web Site Public IP Address in Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template, in this template, there are two resources, one is storage account the other is web site. How can I get the ip address of the web site and put it in the allowed ip address of the storage account?

thanks

Comment: when you say website, you mean app service or something else?

Comment: yes, I mean "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms" or "Microsoft.Web/sites"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use 'outputs' in 'linked templates' to accomplish it. For more information, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#get-values-from-linked-template) section of the article.